# win10 some sort of weather msn app starting up, not showing in taskmanager or installed apps

Tags: windows-10, windows-live-messenger

I'd appreciate any help you can give.  I'm running Win 10 Home build 19041.1052.
Recently a new app has mysteriously appeared.  It looks like the MSN taskbar app, which I don't have installed on my system. See attached jpg of weather and task manager.  Notice there's no "MSN" app listed in the task manager.

[image]

2 questions:

1. how do I find this app?
2. how do I permanently uninstall it?

Malwarebytes and AVG say nothing's wrong, but I still don't trust the widget/app/whatever, especially since it doesn't show as any type of installed application.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to uninstall it.  It is a new feature of windows and not a 3rd party install.

I don't like it either but it is built into the explorer now.

1. Right click on the taskbar.
2. Go to "News and Interest"
3. Select "Turn Off"
4. Celebrate

Comment: well, I feel stupid.  LOL -- Seriously though thank you for alleviating my concern, as I genuinely thought it was a 3rd party install.  Thought some new spyware or something like that got on my system.

Comment: You're not stupid - this unannounced new feature caught me also by surprise, and I had exactly the same reaction as you, before I angrily turned it off.

Comment: @harrymc - [It was actually announced back in April](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/04/22/personalized-content-at-a-glance-introducing-news-and-interests-on-the-windows-10-taskbar/)

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm signed up for multiple Microsoft newsletters, but none of them ever warned about this UI change. Windows 11 will have more such surprises, I'm sure.

Comment: @harrymc - The only newsletter I read is the Windows developer blog.